# Find non-numeric value in a group of rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need group values and assign a status according to a value in a group. Example:

| Client | Purchase | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client 1 | Purchase 1 | Status 1 |
| Client 1 | Purchase 2 | Status 2 |
| Client 1 | Purchase 3 | Status 1 |
| Client 2 | Purchase 4 | Status 2 |
| Client 2 | Purchase 5 | Status 3 |
| Client 3 | Purchase 4 | Status 1 |
| Client 3 | Purchase 5 | Status 4 |

Group by the client and assign a status IF status 1 in the group THEN client status = status 1 ELSEIF status 2 in the group THEN client status = status 2 etc.

Expected result:

| Client | Main Status |
| --- | --- |
| Client 1 | Status 1 |
| Client 2 | Status 2 |
| Client 3 | Status 1 |

Status 1 has the highest priority, Status 4 - lowest.

Comment: Please add desired output based on your sample data. Also consider adding a couple more rows of sample data to capture more scenarios. Also, how many different "status" values are there? What have you tried? Basically looking for "smallest" status in group?

Comment: If your data very reliably <abcdef>i, and i corresponds to the status, you can get around any hardcoding with something like `select client, min(cast(regexp_replace(some_field, '[^0-9]+','') as int)) as status_int from some_test_data group by client` . (untested for BigQuery, but it's a pretty vanilla regex.) Otherwise you'll have to use some kind of conditional aggregation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the first table, let's say T1:

```
SELECT client, SUBSTR (StatusGroup, 1, INSTR (StatusGroup, '-') - 1) "Main Status"
  FROM (  SELECT client,
                 LISTAGG (status, '-')
                 WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY
                                   DECODE (status,
                                           'Status 1', 1,
                                           'Status 2', 2,
                                           'Status 3', 3,
                                           4))    StatusGroup
            FROM T1
        GROUP BY client)
```

Comment: Please use code formatting, not  **bold**, when posting code.

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
select * 
from(
  select *
    ,row_number()over(partition by Client order by StatusOrder) rnk
  from(
    select *
     ,case when Status='Status 1' then 1
           when Status='Status 2' then 2
           when Status='Status 3' then 3
           when Status='Status 4' then 4
      else null
      end StatusOrder
    from test
   )x
 )y
where rnk=1
```

Output

| Client | Purchase | Status | StatusOrder | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client 1 | Purchase 3 | Status 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Client 2 | Purchase 4 | Status 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Client 3 | Purchase 4 | Status 1 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
SELECT Client, Statuses[Main_Status_Index - 1] AS Main_Status
FROM (
  SELECT Client, 
    ANY_VALUE(Statuses) AS Statuses, 
    MIN(RANGE_BUCKET(Status, Statuses)) AS Main_Status_Index
  FROM your_table, 
  UNNEST([STRUCT(['Status 1', 'Status 2', 'Status 3', 'Status 4'] AS Statuses)])
  GROUP BY Client
)
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]